# Â-genus of a complex manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, characteristic-classes, kahler-manifolds

I am trying to understand the proof of the Riemann-Roch-Hirzebruch theorem using the index theorem (*Heat Kernel and Dirac operators*, [BGV]), and at the end they say that since $$TM \otimes \mathbb{C} = T^{1,0}M \oplus T^{0,1}M, $$
with $M$ a Kähler manifold, then

$$ Â(TM) = det \left( \frac{R^+}{e^{\frac{R^+}{2}}-e^{\frac{-R^+}{2}}} \right), $$

with $R^+$ is the curvature of the bundle $T^{1,0}M$ and knowing that the defintion of the Â-genus is

$$ Â(TM) :=  det^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \frac{\frac{R}{2}}{sinh \left( \frac{R}{2} \right) } \right), $$

with $R$ the Riemannian curvature of $M$.

But unfortunately, I do not see how that works. Any help would be nice, thank you.

Comment: Could you specify what it is you are asking about ? Is it your second equality? Also a page reference might be helpful.